# Selecting features with attachments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attachments

Is there a way to select features in a layer that have an attachment?

I want to identify all features on a map that have an attachment associated with it

Comment: I think you need to write custom script in Python.

Comment: @Walt, What format is your layer, shapefile, geodatabase feature class, or SDE feature class?

Answer (score 3):

I tried it with a file geodatabase by opening the attachment table then joining it to the feature layer that had the attachments:

Layer with attachments called ws, table in geodatabase called ws_attach joined using rel_objectid from ws_attach to the objectid in the ws feature class